# PHP Checkbox Values Not Saved During Error Check or Posting

Tags: php, forms, checkbox, error-handling

The "newvar_" values for "029, 032 and 033" are not being remembered during error-checking, nor are they being posted when a corrected form is submitted.

The "name" field works correctly both on error checking and posting.

The form default for the all checkboxes is not selected.

The user should be able to select only the forms they wish. Their selection should post to the txt file along with their name.

The validation library am using can be found at: http://www.benjaminkeen.com/software/php_validation

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

```
    <?php                                                       

    // Eliminate server error notices except for parse errors                                                       
        error_reporting(E_PARSE);                                                   

    // Receiving variables                                                      
        $errors = array(); // set the errors array to empty, by default                                                 
        $fields = array(); // stores the field values                                                   

        if (isset($_POST['submit']))                                                    
        {                                                   

    // Import the validation library                                                        
        require("../include/validation.php");                                                   

        $rules = array(); // stores the validation rules                                                    

    // Rules specific to this form                                                      
        $rules[] = "required,name,Please enter Your Name.";                                                 
        $rules[] = "length<71,name,Your Name is too long.";                                                 

    // Check the user's entries for errors based upon above rules                                                       
        $errors = validate_fields($_POST, $rules);                                                  

    // If there were errors, re-populate the form fields with user entries                                                      
        if (!empty($errors))                                                    
        {                                                   
        $fields = $_POST;                                                       
      }                                                     
    // If there were no errors                                                      
        else                                                    
        {                                                   

    // Redirect to a "thank you" page URL shown below                                                       
        header("Location: thank-you.php");                                                      
            }                                               
        }                                                   

    // Count the errors. If none process the form data                                                      
        if (count($errors) == 0) {                                                  

    // Location of flat file database - absolute path                                                       
        $datafile_01 = '/home/domain/public_html/Forms.txt';                                                    

    // Strip-out the HTML tags                                                      
        $_GET   = filter_input_array(INPUT_GET, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);                                                    
        $_POST  = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);                                                   

    //  Write successfully submitted form data to flat file database                                                    
        if ($_POST['submit']) {                                                 
            $file = fopen($datafile_01, "a");                                               
        if (!$file) {                                                   
            die("Can't write to database file");                                                
        }                                                   

    // Set timezone to match delivery location                                                      
        date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');                                                  
        $date = date('Y m-d  g:i:s a');                                                 

    // Select and code the fields being posted                                                      
        $name = $_POST['name'];$name=($name);                                                   

    //FORMS & SUPPLIES                                                      

        // Standard Forms they requested                                                    
        // Change the checkbox 'on' to something else (defined by $Newvar)                                                  

        if($Form_F_029 == 'on') { $Newvar_029 = &$Form_F_029; $Newvar_029 = "X"; }                                                  
        if($Form_F_032 == 'on') { $Newvar_032 = &$Form_F_032; $Newvar_032 = "X"; }                                                  
        if($Form_F_033 == 'on') { $Newvar_033 = &$Form_F_033; $Newvar_033 = "X"; }                                                  

    // Format the fields for the flat file                                                      
        fwrite($file,                                                   
    "Name:\t $name\n

REQUESTED FORMS AND SUPPLIES:\n
STANDARD FORMS ++++++++++++++++++++
Form F-029:\t $Newvar_029
Form F-032:\t $Newvar_032
Form F-033:\t $Newvar_033\n

=============================================================================== EOF =\n\n);"                                                        
            fclose($file);                                              
        }                                                   

    // Format and send email notice of successful submittal                                                     
        if ($_POST['submit']) {                                                 

            $sn_header = "From: Inquiries Database\n"                                               
              . "Reply-To: no_reply@domain.com\n";                                              
            $sn_subject = "Ordering Supplies Request";                                              
            $sn_email_to = "someone@domain.com";                                                
            $sn_message = "Please check the database for a recent submission.\n\n"                                              
            . "This is a post-only message.\n\n"                                                
            . "Do not reply.\n";                                                
            @mail($sn_email_to, $sn_subject ,$sn_message ,$sn_header ) ;                                                
        }                                                   
    }                                                       
    ?>                                                      

    <!DOCTYPE HTML>                                                     
    <html>                                                      
        <head>                                                  
            <title>Form Test</title>                                                
            <meta charset="utf-8" />                                                    
            <meta name="viewport"                                               
                content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />                                            
    <?php //This CSS needed only for forms to style Modal ?>                                                        
            <link rel="stylesheet"                                              
                href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"                                            
                media="screen" />                                                                                                   
        </head>                                                 
        <body>                                                  

    <!-- Wrapper -->                                                        

                <div id="wrapper" class="divided">                                          

                        <section class="wrapper style1 align-left">                                 

                            <div class="inner">                             

                                <h2 class="color-1">Measuring &amp; Ordering Supplies</h2>                          

                                                <form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" name="inquiry" method="post">          
                                                    <div class="field">     
                                                        <label  style="margin:1rem 0 .25rem 0"><i class=" color-1 fa fa-star"></i> Your Name:</label>   
                                                        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="<?=$fields['name']?>" />    
                                                    </div>      

                                                    <div class="field" style="padding-top:1rem">        
                                                        <label style="font-size:110%; margin-bottom:0"><b class="color-1">Standard Forms</b> &nbsp; 
                                                            <span style="font-weight:300; font-size:80%">Check box to order | Click name to download PDF</span><br />
                                                        </label>    
                                                    </div>      
                                                        <div class="field third first" style="padding-top:10px">    
                                                            <input type="checkbox" id="Form_F_029" name="Form_F_029" <?php if($Form_F_029 == "on"){echo "CHECKED";}?> />
                                                            <label for="F_029"><a href="../../../forms_resources/order-forms/pdf/Form_F_029.pdf">Form F 029</a>
                                                            </label>
                                                        </div>  
                                                        <div class="field third" style="padding-top:10px">  
                                                            <input type="checkbox" id="Form_F_032" name="Form_F_032" <?php if($Form_F_032 == "on"){echo "CHECKED";}?> />
                                                            <label for="Form_F_032"><a href="../../../forms_resources/order-forms/pdf/Form_F_032.pdf">Form F 032</a>
                                                            </label>
                                                        </div>  
                                                        <div class="field third" style="padding-top:10px">  
                                                            <input type="checkbox" id="Form_F_033" name="Form_F_033" <?php if($Form_F_033 == "on"){echo "CHECKED";}?> />
                                                            <label for="Form_F_033"><a href="../../../forms_resources/order-forms/pdf/Form_F_033.pdf">Form F 033</a>
                                                            </label>
                                                        </div>  

                                                    <ul class="actions" style="padding-top:30px">       
                                                        <li><input type="submit" class="button small" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit Request" /></li>  
                                                    </ul>       
                                                </form>         
                            </div>                              

                            <div id="error" title="Form Errors:">                               
                                <?php                           
                                // if $errors is not empty display them in the modal                            
                                if (!empty($errors))                            
                                    {                       
                                    echo "<div style=\"padding:15px 15px 0 15px\">";                        
                                            echo "<ul style=\"margin-bottom:20px\">";               
                                    foreach ($errors as $error)                     
                                        echo "<li style=\"font-size:15px; padding:5px\">$error</li>";                   
                                        echo "</ul></div>";                 
                                    }                       
                                ?>                          
                            </div>                              

                        </section>                                  
    <!-- Footer -->                                                     
                </div>                                          
    <!-- Scripts -->                                                        
    <?php include $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/assets/includes/php/javascripts-01.php"; ?>                                                     
    <?php // Supporting scripts for Error Modal ?>                                                      
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>                                                          
            <script>                                                
                 <?php if( isset( $_POST["submit"] ) ){ ?>                                              
                     $('#error').dialog({                                               
                         height: 380,                                               
                         width: 260,                                                
                         modal: true,                                               
                         resizable: false,                                              
                         dialogClass: 'no-close error-dialog'                                               
                     });                                                
                 <?php } ?>                                             
            </script>                                               
        </body>                                                 
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The values of $Form_F_029, _032, _033 are never set.

You copied the POST variables into $fields:

```
$fields = $_POST;
```

So this worked as intended:

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="<?=$fields['name']?>" />
```

But uses of $Form_F_0xx are treated as null, undefined or false depending on context:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="Form_F_029" name="Form_F_029" <?php if($Form_F_029 == "on"){echo "CHECKED";}?> />
```

You could fix this by setting

```
$Form_F_029 = $fields['Form_F_029'];
```

or

```
$Form_F_029 = $_POST['Form_F_029'];
```

etc.

For debugging problems like this it can help to include the values of variables and arrays in your output, for example in a comment or pre tag:

```
echo "<!-- 29= $Form_F_029, 32 = $Form_F_032  -->";  // DEBUGGING
echo "<pre>- 29= $Form_F_029, 32 = $Form_F_032  </pre>";  // DEBUGGING
```

Just remember to delete them or comment them out later.

Comment: Perhaps am not your recommendations.

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding? I replaced my original code: 

    <?php if($Form_F_029 == "on"){echo "CHECKED";} ?> 

with:

    <?php $Form_F_029 = $fields['Form_F_029']; ?>

and:

    <?php $Form_F_029 = $_POST['Form_F_029']; ?>

Neither were saved during error checking or or posted to the text file.

Comment: To clarify... I tried each of your recommendations one at a time, not together.

Comment: Finally figured-out what you meant. A Eureka moment for me!

adding: `$Form_F_029 = $_POST['Form_F_029'];`

under: `$name = $_POST['name'];$name=($name);`

set the values!

Comment: Great.  You might also need to set them for the error case not just the success case, be sure to test both.